# Handling onclick event if no GUI element was clicked

Tags: javascript, dom-events

To make it more clear what I need to do, here is the structure of the search form / HTML page I am working with:

```
  ---
  |A|
  ---
 
 ---------   ---------   ---------
 |       |   |       |   |       |
 |   B   |   |   B   |   |   B   |
 |       |   |       |   |       |
 ---------   ---------   ---------
 
 ---------------------------------    ---------
 |                               |    |   C   |
 |                               |    ---------
 |                               |
 |               X               |    ---------
 |                               |    |   C   |
 |                               |    ---------
 |                               |
 ---------------------------------
```

The boxes `A`, `B`, `C` are buttons which can be clicked by the user.
The `X` is the content are where the search result will be displayed.

The boxes behave at the moment like this:

- Click on `A` returns to the previous site (= a back button)
- Click on `B` and `C` apply filter and submit the form (= retrieving the result set of the search)
- Click on `X` does nothing - the search result shown here

This works all fine and well.

---

My new requirement is:

**When the user clicks "anything else" then `A`, `B`, `C` or `X` then a help message appears in the content area.**

As you can imagine, the HTML of the boxes is fairly different and nested, only the boxes of the same type (= same letter) share a CSS class.

E. g. `C` looks like this:

---

My first thought on how to implement this was:

- Attaching an `onclick` listener to `document.body`
- Check if the `event.target` is `A`, `B`, `C` or `X` or contained in any of them
- If not, then the user has not clicked a GUI element and the help message is being displayed

This could be made more easy by attaching a common CSS class (`gui-element`) to all GUI elements so the document `onclick` event handler checks only if the event target has this common class.

The drawback is that if any new element e. g. `D` is introduced in the HTML it must have this CSS class, too.

Do you think the above approach is good or is there a more "elegant" way of doing this?

**EDIT:**

A few more details:

- I am using YUI2 as JavaScript framework
- I know the whole idea of the help message appearing `onclick` might be ...uh annoying, but I have to do what I am told, sorry

Comment: Please don't do this.  Some of us are compulsive clickers that randomly click and/or select while we're reading.  If you want a Help system, put a button called, "Help" somewhere.

Comment: Hehe, if it would be my decision, I would not do this. But its not my company and so I gotta do what I am told. ;-) But this wont be a web app, it will run on a touchscreen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with your first thought, because it would be more maintainable (at least for me)

Answer (score 0):

You can add an onclick handler for the body or some super element, and then stop the event from propogating when you click on of the other elements so it doesn't bubble and you only get the one effect.

```
function doSomething(e)
{
    //handle event
    if (!e) 
        var e = window.event;  //if ie do this
    e.cancelBubble = true;     //ie's stopPropagation method
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();  //w3's stopPropagation
}
```

[source/tutorial on javascript event bubbling](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html)

But make sure you do some testing in different browser to make sure it works correctly. :D